# Defining racket contracts with a custom predicate

Tags: racket, contract

I'm just starting to learn about contracts (via exercism.io) and so I have made a contract that is:

```
[step1 (-> (and/c number?
                  less-than-one-hundred?)
            string?)]
```

What I *think* I'm saying is the function will take a number less than one hundred (which is a function defined as:

```
(define (less-than-one-hundred? n)
  (< n 100))
```

But when I call the function like this:

```
(step1 100)
```

No contract violation.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a concrete example of what Soegaard's answer is saying:

**def-step1.rkt**

```
#lang racket

(provide (contract-out
          [step1 (-> (and/c number?
                            less-than-one-hundred?)
                     string?)]))

(define (less-than-one-hundred? n)
  (< n 100))

(define (step1 x) "")
```

**use-step1.rkt**

```
#lang racket

(require "def-step1.rkt")

(step1 100)
```

This produces a contract violation like you expect, and in particular, it *blames* `use-step1.rkt`, a different "contract party" than `def-step1.rkt` where the contract came from:

```
step1: contract violation
  expected: less-than-one-hundred?
  given: 100
  in: an and/c case of
      the 1st argument of
      (->
       (and/c number? less-than-one-hundred?)
       string?)
  contract from: .../def-step1.rkt
  blaming: .../use-step1.rkt
   (assuming the contract is correct)
```

Answer (score 2):

Contracts are only enforced over module boundaries. 
This means that if your expression `(step1 100)` is in the same module as you contract, the input is not checked.

However if you export `step1` with a contract, and then in another module imports `step1` and calls it, the contract will be checked.